# Fedora + Nginx + Wordpress virtual host on EC2 generating links to actual host name

Tags: nginx, fedora, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I'm currently trying to set up a virtual host in Nginx so that I can run a wordpress server as though it were on a different domain. The problem I'm currently having is that the wordpress server, while displaying when I go to 'http://example-domain.com/blog/', has every link pointing at the amazon host, 'ec2-***-***-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com'. I would like for all of these links to resolve using the 'example-domain.com' host.

My Main Nginx conf file (nginx.conf) is:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                  '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  2;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    #
    # The default server
    #
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    }
}
```

The virtual host is set up with the following conf:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example-domain.com;

    root   /var/www/example-domain.com/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

The wordpress folder is located at /var/www/example-domain.com/html/blog/. Does anyone have any idea why all the wordpress links on the front page use the ec2 host name and not the one defined in the virtual host configuration? If so please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because wordpress keeps the URL/domain name in the database settings.
You need to login to the wordpress wp-admin and update the site url or simply update it directly in the database.

Comment: That was it! Totally noob question....thanks for your help!